# Long-term access token in API Management REST API

Tags: azure-api-management

I use API Management REST API to create and manage users, and I have to regenerate the access token every 30 days. It's a bit of a hassle to update my web applications every month.

Is there a better way?

I know I can do it programmatically, too, but I am not sure it's a healthy practice to do it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you do via APIM SAS token you can do via ARM. With ARM you can create service identity and use it to manage your resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: That looks like the general direction that APIM will be moving to, thanks. Is there a walkthru how to set up the APIM users using Azure Resource Manager?

Comment: APIM's direct API was always an optional thing you have to enable to use. But any service in azure has to be manageable via ARM. Here is the REST API to create/update users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user/createorupdate

Comment: Thanks, Vitaliy. I mean, how do I connect between the two? I already use the /Users API, and I registered an ARM app and gave it a permission in my APIM. I successfully issued a token request and obtained a token. Now when I replace my SAS with the new token (prefixed by `Bearer`), I get 401 - Unauthorized. Am I missing a step? Should I open a new issue for that?

Comment: There are two ways to address APIM service. As ARM you'll be calling URLs that start with https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/.../users... This will require ARM token that you can get through AAD.
Alternatively you can use APIM direct API by calling https://....management.azure-api.net/users/... that accepts SAS token and has to be enabled first to work. It is advisdd to go with ARM approach unless you're facing some problems, like ARM throttling your requests (very rare)

Comment: Perfect! It works. A bit more hassle with an extra call, but not a big deal. Thanks a lot, @VitaliyKurokhtin.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of approaches to handle the access token.

To be simplest, you can put the token to a cache system, and set the expire time (like using SETEX in Redis),  which is 30 days after in your case. So after 30 days, your access token will be removed automatically by the cache system.

When you need access token but you found it is missing, it means that the access token has expired or you never generated the access token. Whatever, you can generate the access token in your program and put it to the cache system. After that, in next 30 days, you can always use that access token.

In addition, due to time differences between your machine and the servers, it's recommended that set the expire time in your cache system a little bit before the real expire time. So in your case, you can set the expire time with 29 days in your cache system, which guarantee the access token is absolutely valid in remote server.

Comment: But that's not what I want. I just want a token that does not expire that quickly. I know I can play with it programmatically, I just don't want this kind of complexity.

Comment: @VadimBerman No. Doing it programmatically is the most convenient way since once your program has been tested, you don't need to do anything after. And you don't need to update your application every month since the access token is not a magic number to your program because you use your code to automatically generate it without any manual thing, so it can be dynamic.

Comment: maybe just extending it by a year, like with most other access tokens, may do the trick? You understand that you need some kind of authentication or another connectivity to the cache system, right? So you're not solving much.

Comment: emm... I think, if you really care about stability of cache systems, you can refer to  backup mechanism of them. But in most cases, you don't need them because even the access token lost occasionally, you can found that it is missing and could regenerate it very quickly following my method. And as for authentication and connectivity problem, I think you don't need to care about them because no matter how you do those thing, you won't get stuck in 99.9% cases.

Comment: Besides, this solution is far more simple than updating web application every time you need refresh the access token.

Comment: It's not the "stability of the cache systems". It's the reluctance to engage in creation of a Rube Goldberg machine for something trivial. If "every time" was a year, it would be perfectly fine.

Comment: yeah, "every time" is a pretty dynamic concept. It could be 30 days, 1 year, 3 years or even forever. It is all about you. I really don't know why it is an another Rube Goldberg machine. It's just a kind of programming pattern with caching. If you just think it is not trivial, you can also write the access token in your code and update it every time when you get error that tells your access token is not available any more :)